# How to get each customer sales and list them in one page sort by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have pages for my each customer like these; Main,Customer1,Customer2,Customer3

Each customer page contains these table;

Customer1
| DATE         | Product           | Total|
| --------     | --------------    | -------------- |
| 5.07.2023    | apple             | 20             |
| 10.08.2023   | banana            | 30             |

On the main page, I am trying to list all customer sales in **August** with the date order

THANKS!

I tried INDIRECT formula but it doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried `query`?

Comment: @cnavar i just editted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recommendation:

Try using `QUERY` instead of `INDIRECT`. Let me know if this works for you:

```
=QUERY({ Customer1!A:D; Customer2!A:D; Customer3!A:D }, "select * WHERE Col1 >= date '" & TEXT(DATEVALUE("01/08/2023"), "yyyy-dd-mm") & "'and Col1 < date '" & TEXT(DATEVALUE("01/09/2023"), "yyyy-dd-mm") & "'")
```

You can add multiple sheets inside `{}`, separated by `;`. This formula assumes that the date is always on the first column of the sheet. Feel free to change the column as needed

### Reference:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB&sjid=5321592072049525126-AP)

Comment: It doesnt work. I am not sure but this code get only 1 customer. I just edited and and more detail. Could you check

Comment: Hi. It's possible to query frm multiple sheets. I've updated the answer based on your edits to the question.